# Microsoft Word Can't do "Save As"

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word file, I want to create a PDF file. For that, I need the "Save As" dialog. I click on File/Save As — and nothing happens. No dialog. It just returns to the screen I had before I clicked File.

What's wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: you can also select print then save as pdf

Comment: @SarmenB. Only if you have the right print driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know what went wrong, but I found online discussion where people had fixed this problem by deleting all the registry entries containing Word preferences. I tried it and it works. Go [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/921541) for detailed instructions and a automated tool that works very well.